# RegEx - Add space after word with comma

Tags: php, regex

I want to add a space after a word with a comma.

It just works partly.

```
$srcString = "AA,BB,CC, DD, EE";


// Variant A
$string = preg_replace('/(\D)(\,)(\D)/','$1, $3', $srcString);

// Variant B
//$string = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z]+)(\,)([a-zA-Z]+)/','$1, $3', $srcString);


echo '<pre>';
echo 'Source: ' . $srcString;
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Target: ' . $string;
echo '</pre>';
```

With variant A the result looks like this:
Source: AA,BB,CC, DD, EE
Target: AA, BB, CC,  DD,  EE
Here are 2 spaced before DD and EE.

With variant B the result looks like this:
Source: AA,BB,CC, DD, EE
Target: AA, BB,CC, DD, EE
Looks fine except BB,CC has no space.

How could this be resolved?

Comment: `\D` matches any character that is not a decimal digit, so it captures the space before `DD` as well.

Comment: You may accept the answer that has a best fit to your problem by clicking on the 'v'. Check this figure for more information: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwTL.png

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a lookahead.

```
$string = preg_replace('/(,)(?=[^\s])/', ', ', $srcString);
```

`(,)` Capturing group for the comma

`(?=[^\s])` Lookahead: Must not be followed by a whitespace

Comment: Thank you. But it should only applied for letters not for numbers.

Comment: you may change the regex to `/(,)(?=[a-zA-z])/`, then it will match only commas followed by letters

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is working too.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it with the comma instead of the letters, and use a single letter instead of 'one-or-more'.

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\,)([a-zA-Z])/','$1 $2', $srcString);
```

Comment: Thank you. But the 'BB,CC' are removed. It will look like this:
Source: AA,BB,CC, DD, EE, 11,22, 33
Target: AA, , , DD, EE, 11,22, 33

Comment: I fixed. It should work now

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is working.

Answer (score 0):

A **non-regex** way to achieve what you want using `array_map`, `trim` etc,

```
<?php
$srcString = "AA,BB,CC,  DD, EE"; #varient 1
#$srcString = "AA,BB,CC, DD, EE"; #varient 2
#$srcString = "AA,BB,CC, DD,  EE"; #varient 3
$result = array_map('trim',explode(',',$srcString));
echo implode(', ', $result);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/e6GJf